# Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown while creating 'winui' new project in visual studio

Tags: winui-3

I open visual studio 2022 and click on create a new project. And then choose **Blank page, Packaged(WinUI 3 in Desktop)** and click next. I Enter the project name and set location for the project. When I click next, I got error "Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown."

[System.Exception Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s0NM.png)

Comment: Please add more detail, there's no way we can help with so few information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.